# UICollectionView custom flow layout

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using UICollectionView custom flow layout in my project. When we set UICollectionViewFlowLayout to our custom collection view layout, the iOS considers the scroll direction to be vertical by default and when we increase the cell size beyond a certain limit it places an inset to the the cell in the left by itself(which can't be reset to zero). Now, through code I set the scroll direction to be horizontal. When I run the app the left inset comes at the top. 
I would really be grateful if anyone replicates my problem and find an appropriate solution.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot? I didnt understand your problem. Then how can i replicate your issue

Comment: Make a custom flow layout. assign it to your collection view. increase the cell size to say 600X600 and just check the cell coordinates. There is a default inset there. Thats the bug I found with UICollectionView.

Comment: What do you mean by custom flow layout? is it sub class of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`(made your own layout by subclassing)  or just an instance of UICollectionViewFlowLayout that you applied to the collectionView explicitly??

Comment: subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout